# Array Comparison in Php, and find the diff in values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I want to compare two arrays in php. My arrays looks like this

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [row1] => 1458)
[1] => Array ( [Id] => 2 [row1] => 16) 
[2] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [row1] => 115) 
[3] => Array ( [Id] => 4 [row1] => 18) 
[4] => Array ( [Id] => 5 [row1] => 13) 
[5] => Array ( [Id] => 6 [row1] => 13) 
[6] => Array ( [Id] => 7 [row1] => 131)
)

Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [row1] => 158)
[1] => Array ( [Id] => 2 [row1] => 165) 
[2] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [row1] => 111) 
[3] => Array ( [Id] => 4 [row1] => 186) 
[4] => Array ( [Id] => 5 [row1] => 3)
)
```

Firstly, array1 size and array2 sizes were not equal always. Id value in array1 may or may not present in array2, If the value is not present, function have to print the total index in array3, like

```
[someindex] => Array ( [Id] => 6 [row1] => 13 )
```

if it is present, function should subtract the row1 of array1 to row1 of array2 and print in array3, like this

```
[someindex] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [row1] => 1300)
```

and my final output should be,

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [row1] => 1300)
[1] => Array ( [Id] => 2 [row1] => -149) 
[2] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [row1] => 4) 
[3] => Array ( [Id] => 4 [row1] => -168) 
[4] => Array ( [Id] => 5 [row1] => 10) 
[5] => Array ( [Id] => 6 [row1] => 13) 
[6] => Array ( [Id] => 7 [row1] => 131)
)
```

Can any one help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you either have to make the second array searchable by using the `Id` value as the keys or write a search function. I'm choosing the former:

```
$searchable = array_reduce($array2, function(&$result, $item) {
    return $result + array($item['Id'] => $item['row1']);
}, array());
```

The [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) function starts with an empty array and builds it using the array addition operator; this creates an array that can be dereferenced using the id.

Then you perform a map operation on the first array:

```
$array3 = array_map(function($item) use ($searchable) {
    $value = isset($searchable[$item['Id']]) ? $searchable[$item['Id']] : 0;
    $item['row1'] -= $value;
//    $item['row2'] = $item['row1'] - $value;
    return $item;
}, $array1);
```

Doing a map operation preserves the original array and creates a new one with the values you choose inside a callback function.

Comment: But, what if I had 10000 of records in my array? does it take time?

Comment: @Sreenath My tests have shown that this method is 75% slower than mine. Average with the above = 0.145, average with mine = 0.083. Though to be fair, I'm not sure at what size the gaps really start to appear, so it depends on what size arrays you're using

Comment: But jack, What If I want to save in diff in row2?

Comment: SmokeyPHP, I don't know your name but I had a same question for you.

Comment: @Sreenath The time for 10k records is small; small enough to not matter :) if you want to save the difference in another field, simply change `$item['row1'] -= $value;` with `$item['row2'] = $item['row1'] - $value;`.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP The 75% doesn't mean much in this case, especially because my answer is O(n) instead of O(n*n) :)

Comment: @Jack let's not disregard the `break` now.. and times are times I'm afraid - you can't choose to ignore them

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I'm not disregarding the `break;` but a linear search is defined as an O(n) operation. Though, granted, my solution is O(n log n). What we don't know is how those original arrays are populated, so to speak of times is purely speculative.

Comment: @Jack Indeed, hence my final sentence on my previous comment "I'm not sure at what size the gaps really start to appear, so it depends on what size arrays you're using". I of course don't believe in any way that your example code will always be 75% slower - there may be sizes where it's faster, others where it's slower and others where the difference is indistinguishable.

Comment: @Sreenath Any particular reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: @Jack. Oh sorry jack. I was appreciating all the ans for the questions i posted. By mistakenly i unaccepted yours. I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: @Sreenath No worries; perhaps you had changed your mind, just wanted to make sure it was still correct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = Array ( 
    0 => Array ('Id' => 1, 'row1' => 1458)
    ,1 => Array ('Id' => 2, 'row1' => 16) 
    ,2 => Array ('Id' => 3, 'row1' => 115) 
    ,3 => Array ('Id' => 4, 'row1' => 18) 
    ,4 => Array ('Id' => 5, 'row1' => 13) 
    ,5 => Array ('Id' => 6, 'row1' => 13) 
    ,6 => Array ('Id' => 7, 'row1' => 131)
);
$arr2 = Array ( 
    0 => Array('Id' => 1, 'row1' => 158)
    ,1 => Array('Id' => 2, 'row1' => 165) 
    ,2 => Array('Id' => 3, 'row1'=> 111) 
    ,3 => Array('Id' => 4, 'row1' => 186) 
    ,4 => Array('Id' => 5, 'row1' => 3)
);
$final = array();
foreach($arr1 as $k => $sec)
{
    $sub = 0;
    foreach($arr2 as $sec2)
    {
        if($sec2['Id']==$sec['Id'])
        {
            $sub = $sec2['row1'];
            break;
        }
    }
    $sec['row1'] -= $sub;
    //Or to save to another element:
    //$sec['row2'] = $sec['row1']-$sub;
    $final[] = $sec;
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($final,true).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [row1] => 1300)
    [1] => Array ( [Id] => 2 [row1] => -149) 
    [2] => Array ( [Id] => 3 [row1] => 4) 
    [3] => Array ( [Id] => 4 [row1] => -168) 
    [4] => Array ( [Id] => 5 [row1] => 10) 
    [5] => Array ( [Id] => 6 [row1] => 13) 
    [6] => Array ( [Id] => 7 [row1] => 131)
)
```

Comment: @Sreenath Do note that the actual Id value is not being used for the lookup.

Comment: @Sreenath Please note that my answer has been updated - as Jack quite rightly pointed out, this wasn't linking elements by the `'Id'` element. It is now doing so correctly.

Comment: Modifying arrays in-place is a dangerous affair btw; what if you needed to use the old value of `$arr1` again?

Comment: @Jack Yea I originally wrote the code with a new `$final` array, but figured I'd change it to just modify the original unless the OP specified otherwise, so as to not use duplicate data (larger array sizes could lead to pointless increase in memory usage, if we start adding extra copies)

Comment: But I don't want to disturb the first array, I want the output in another array.

Comment: @Sreenath The answer has been updated to save the output to `$final` and I've added a commented line in case you want the subtracted value to go into `row2` instead of overwriting `row1`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this exactly what you want, but you can check if a key exists with [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $array2)) {
            $array3[] = $v - $array2[$k];
        } else {
            $array3[] = $v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates an indexing array (`$new`) in case the main keys don't match of in the original arrays.

```
$arr = array ( 
    0 => array ( 'Id' => '1','row1' => 1458),
    1 => array ( 'Id' => '2','row1' => 16),
    2 => array ( 'Id' => '3','row1' => 115),
    3 => array ( 'Id' => '4','row1' => 18),
    4 => array ( 'Id' => '5','row1' => 13),
    5 => array ( 'Id' => '6','row1' => 13),
    6 => array ( 'Id' => '7','row1' => 131));
$arr2 = array ( 
    0 => array ( 'Id' => '1','row1' => 158),
    1 => array ( 'Id' => '2','row1' => 165),
    2 => array ( 'Id' => '3','row1' => 111),
    3 => array ( 'Id' => '4','row1' => 186),
    4 => array ( 'Id' => '5','row1' => 3));
$new = array();
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value){
    $new[$value['Id']] = $value['row1'];
}
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if (isset($new[$value['Id']])){
        $arr[$key]['row1'] -= $new[$value['Id']];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```